# Is it possible to work out HTML5 utilisation of session/local storage?

Tags: html, local-storage, session-storage, sessionstorage

Is it possible to work out utilisation of session storage?

Ideally to return current size of site session storage contents

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: What do you mean by "size"? You can use the [length property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/length) to determine the number of items in storage.

Comment: Length is perfect ;)

Comment: Think I overlooked the obvious. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this and it matched the local storage size [here](https://arty.name/localstorage.html).

```
function getLocalStorageSize() {
    var key, item, bytes = 0, keys = Object.keys(localStorage);

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        key = keys[i];
        item = localStorage[key];
        bytes += key.length + item.length;
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a somewhat relevant result you can do this:

```
var size = JSON.stringify(localStorage).length; // size in bytes
```

This works because `localStorage` returns the `Object` containing all data stored in it. If you stringify it you can easily get the length (in bytes) of the string.

I say "somewhat relevant" because when stringifying the `Object` quotes are added around the keys and this affects the result. You could otherwise, simply iterate through all the keys in localStorage and sum the lengts of the strings found at those keys.